# RDF vocabulary to define filters over a dataset?

Tags: search, rdf, vocabulary

I have a totally arbitrary data set with objects and their properties. The data set can contain pretty much anything. I want to explicitly mark some of the properties as searchable/filterable (I will use it when generating user interface on top of the data set). For example, let's say my data set contains people:

```
<http://www.jonhdoe.com> a schema:Person ; 
    schema:name "John Doe" .
```

Now I want to state that in my data set, objects can be searched using `schema:name`. So, something like this:

```
schema:name a filters:Filter ;
    rdfs:label "Name of a person" .
```

Based on this definition, I can now generate a form field with given label and let the user search the data set using this field.

Is there an existing vocabulary that would allow me define such meta data over my data set? I tried several vocabulary searches but they weren't giving me nice results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a 100% fit, but I think the [Fresnel vocabulary](https://www.w3.org/2005/04/fresnel-info/) might be close to what you're looking for. It allows you to specify information on how to display RDF data, using the notion of 'lenses' and 'formats'. Lenses define which properties for a given resource/class should be considered for display, formats in turn define *how* things should be rendered/displayed.

You can use this to define a 'searchable' lens, which defines the properties you want to allow search on.